# Running git clone from C# Process ignoring input for passphrase

Tags: c#, git, process

I am attempting to run git clone through a C# process that also passes in the location of the SSH key.

The command:

```
cd C:\\repo-location && SET GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i path\to\.ssh\privKey && git clone git@bitbucket.org:location.git
```

will prompt for the passphrase as expected, however, using Process seems to ignore it so I am getting a "git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey)." error immediately.

What is also interesting is the Process only returns from StandardError.

Here is the code:

```
ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
pInfo.FileName = "C:\\Git\\git-cmd.exe";
pInfo.Arguements = "cd C:\\repo-location && " +
    "SET GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i \"path\to\.ssh\privKey\" && " +
    "git clone git@bitbucket.org:location.git";
pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
pInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process process = Process.Start(pInfo);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine) => {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) && outLine.Data.StartsWith("Enter passphrase")) {
        //Never hits here...
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(password);
    }
});
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine) => {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) && outLine.Data.StartsWith("Enter passphrase")) {
        //Never hits here...
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(password);
    }
});
```

I tried other approaches to get SSH working with git config core.sshCommand but that doesn't even prompt for a passphrase when running from git-cmd.exe.

I prefer NOT to use ssh-agent since there can be a few keys I need to point to.

EDIT:

This can probably be boiled down to allowing a C# process to not eat the prompt for a passphrase and that is the issue with this.  Does anyone have any solutions to that?

MORE INFO:

I noticed that even using the command in cmd.exe and redirecting stdout will also prevent interaction.  But changing the code to not redirect still skips the interaction.

Comment: when you say `when I am NOT running in C# ` ...does that mean when you are not debugging?

Comment: I mean when I am running through git-cmd.exe.  Or even in command prompt itself (if path is set or pointing to C:\Git\cmd\git)

Comment: i see - maybe just comment your code to show the split better between the two scenarios - maybe it's just me but was not obvious at first - thanks

Comment: Maybe still not clear.  If I use Process to run the command, it will not prompt for the passphrase.  It only prompts when running in command prompt or git bash.

Comment: are you running as admin on your machine? - maybe an aspect to bear in mind...

Comment: I just tried that with no avail :(

Comment: have you tried taking away the if statements for the events to see if `anything` gets picked up?

Comment: I have put a breakpoint on the if statements and for StandardError I get: cloning 'project'...  "git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey)." and other SSH errors since the passphrase was not provided.  Also, if the key does not have a passphrase, it is fine because no input is needed.

Comment: Why not use [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/) or another Git client library?

Comment: I actually am using libgit2sharp but I cannot get it to clone since this is using SSH and from what I understand, it is not supported?  I have tried libgit2sharp-SSH and if any server is patched recently, that approach will not work either :(